# How to check which photo is liked by current_user from photos collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have polymorphic assoication like this:

```
class Likes < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :likeable, :polymorphic => true  
end

class Photos < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :likes, :as => :likeable
end
```

In photos#index view i`m displaying 10 photos(with likes count and like button) per page.I want to check which photo is liked by current_user and if it is liked to disable 'like button'. How to do this and what is the best way?

Best regards,
Georgi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways you could go, with various trade offs between speed, ease of use etc. I've assumed your user model has a `has_many :likes` association.

You could do something like

```
current_user.likes.where(:likeable_type => 'Photo', :likeable_id => photo).exists?
```

Although this will fire one db query per photo displayed (although as long as you have the right indexes on the likes table they will be very fast queries).

Another option is to load all the users likes in one go and put them in a hash indexed by likeable_id and likeable_type. This only requires one query per page, but will get slow if users have a lot of likes - you could be loading 3000 likes just to determine the status of the photos you are displaying

Another option would be to load only those likes for the photos you're displaying. If that array was `photos` you could do

```
likes = current_user.likes.where(:likeable_type => 'Photo', :likeable_id => photos)
```

This results in a single query that should be fast (again assuming you have the right indices) and you'll never be fetching more likes than you need.

```
liked = likes.inject({}) {|hash,like| hash[like.likeable_id]=true; hash}
```

Then gives you a hash that will tell you if a photo (identified by its id) was liked: just check the value of `liked[photo.id]`

Comment: Thank you very well explained.

Answer (score 0):

Likes  belongs_to :user 
photo.likes.detect { |l| l.user_id ==  current_user.id}